# Get Value of any Input type

Tags: jquery

The Input types were generated dynamically.
Im searching for an easy way to get the selected or checked values of any input type.

```
<select name="myinput" >
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="myinput" value="Hey Ya!" />
```

Like:

```
var val = $('[name=myinput]').inputval();
```

Thx for help. Marc

Edit: I dont know the type of Input before. It would be great if jquery has a native solution without time expensive type checking.

Comment: Please familiarise yourself with the [API](http://api.jquery.com). This is jQuery 101.

Comment: "Input types generated dynamically". "easy way get selected or checked values of any input type" What if myinput is a radio or a checkbox?

Answer (score 3):

use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
var val = $('[name=myinput]').val();
```

Comment: what if my input is a "select" a "radio" or "checkbox". I dont know the type before!

Comment: `select` will work fine... for `checkbox` and `radio` you need to check whether it is checked using `$(field).is('checked')`

Answer (score 0):

for selecting the selected value better to use [SELECTED](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector

for input type to get the value use [VAL](http://api.jquery.com/val/) selector